# Creating new columns calculating the value in the same row in Linux

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a table:

```
  A B C
X 1 2 3 
Y 4 5 6
Z 7 8 9
```

I want to create two new columns D and E, calculating the average and the value of a formula (A+B)/C respectively to get:

```
  A B C D E
X 1 2 3 2 1
Y 4 5 6 5 1.5
Z 7 8 9 8 1.67
```

How to do that? All post I found from search are calculating values in a column but not row, and output to another file.

Comment: Are the ABCXYZ labels actually part of your file?  If so, you'd be better off removing them and just having the data itself in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given `data.txt` containing:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Run:

```
awk '{$4 = ($1+$2+$3)/3; $5 = ($1+$2)/$3; print}' data.txt
```

Output will be:

```
1 2 3 2 1
4 5 6 5 1.5
7 8 9 8 1.66667
```